# Getting Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8 in Chrome when parsing JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get this error in the console using JSFiddle and Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/YdM8n/2/ when trying to parse a Flickr feed with jQuery.

Code:

```
// a flickr rss feed i am trying to parse.
var yql3 = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fapi.flickr.com%2Fservices%2Ffeeds%2Fphotos_public.gne%3Fid%3D76250020%40N04%26lang%3Den-us%26format%3Drss_200%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?";

$.getJSON(yql3, function(cbfunc) {

    var eachImageArr = $(cbfunc.query.results.rss.channel.item);

    $(eachImageArr).each(function() {
        $('body').append(this.description);
    });

});​
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Was fiddling around, and the last result has some strange content with an array etc, and just removing it fixed the error : http://jsfiddle.net/YdM8n/3/

Comment: @adeneo The array is the problem, but removing it is not the solution. It makes sense to just combine the array's elements and append that, however that would be done...

Comment: @adeneo Lame solution. And you even tested it in a fiddle.

Comment: @Ian - I realize that removing the last object is'nt a solution, I just stated that leaving the last object out got rid of the error.

Comment: @adeneo Good point, shouldn't have taken it so seriously :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the actual JSON returned, you'd notice the possible format of the `description` item can be:

```
"description": ["html stuff", {some object}]
```

When looping through every description, you can check to see if it's an array, if and if it is, append the `[0]` index to the body. Something like:

http://jsfiddle.net/YdM8n/5/

```
var eachImageArr = cbfunc.query.results.rss.channel.item;

$.each(eachImageArr, function() {
    if ($.isArray(this.description)) {
        $("body").append(this.description[0]);
    } else {
        $("body").append(this.description);
    }
});
```

But obviously the API needs investigated more to make sure other special cases can't occur...or at least try to account for something similar.

Comment: Oh man, you were a little late to the party but it's a great answer. I did give you an upvote. Thanks! :)

Comment: Oh trust me, I wasn't late - I've been watching this and trying to figure it out since you asked the question. I was late to the "provide an answer" party. But anyways, this actually provides a solution to your problem. It may not be an all-inclusive answer (since we're not sure what curve balls the API can throw at you now), but it seems to work and not throw an exception...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in the 18th element of the array, the description is actually an array with the first element being what you expect and the second element being another object.

```
description: Array[2]
0: "            <p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/people/jonathanbell/">jonathanbell.ca</a> posted a photo:</p>↵    ↵<p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/jonathanbell/7290239398/" title="120405_sophia_004"><img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7075/7290239398_3c4b7905da_m.jpg" width="180" height="240" alt="120405_sophia_004" /></a></p>↵↵<p>sophia dishaw</p>"
1: Object
    content: "<p>sophia dishaw</p>"
    type: "html"
```

I'm not familiar enough with the flickr api to tell you what the second field is, but it appears to be a name.

Comment: @NuclearGhost Thanks! Good eye! :) I'll have to figure some if statement to check if the item is in fact an array and, if so, use the [0] element (I don't really know the Flickr API either..). Do you all think that's the best way to approach this? Appreciate your help! Thanks again. :)